# Is it possible to exclude a constructor from autofac registration?

Tags: c#, autofac

If I have the following class, is it possible to exclude the copy constructor from Autofac registration?

```
public class A
{
    public A() {}
    public A(A other) { // copy constructor }
    public A(int b) { // some other stuff }
}
```

Basically, I would want autofac to resolve the default constructor, or if the user requested a `Func<int, A>` the third constructor.  I never want autofac to resolve the copy constructor.  Is this possible?

The reason for this is that when I try and use Autofac to inject a `Func<A>`, it results in a circular dependency as Autofac is trying to use the second constructor (it thinks it knows a way to resolve A, but the way to resolve A requires an A).

Comment: I know this might not be the best answer, but I suggest taking a look at how Autofac resolves the dependencies (maybe such a link would be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25380/Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac)

Comment: Can you post your component registrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own [constructor selector](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/IConstructorSelector.cs) that ignores your second constructor:

```
public class AConstructorSelector : IConstructorSelector
{
    public ConstructorParameterBinding SelectConstructorBinding(ConstructorParameterBinding[] constructorBindings)
    {
        if (constructorBindings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("constructorBindings");
        if (constructorBindings.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("constructorBindings");

        if (constructorBindings.Length == 1)
            return constructorBindings[0];

        var withLength = constructorBindings
            .Where(b => !b.TargetConstructor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).Contains(typeof(A)))
            .Select(binding => new { Binding = binding, ConstructorParameterLength = binding.TargetConstructor.GetParameters().Length })
            .ToArray();

        var maxLength = withLength.Max(binding => binding.ConstructorParameterLength);

        var maximal = withLength
            .Where(binding => binding.ConstructorParameterLength == maxLength)
            .Select(ctor => ctor.Binding)
            .ToArray();

        if (maximal.Length == 1)
            return maximal[0];

        throw new DependencyResolutionException("Unable to find constructor");
    }
}
```

And when register your class use it as parameter of the `UsingConstructor`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<A>().UsingConstructor(new AConstructorSelector());
```

See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgUoTF)

Answer (score 1):

Autofac 3.x will automatically create [Implicit Relationship Types](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html), e.g. `Func<A>`, `Lazy<B>`, etc. However you can override the default by registering your own.

`builder.Register<Func<int, A>>(c => (value) => { return new A(value); });`

This is registering the `Func<int, A>` signature and instructing which constructor to use to create this.

Try it out at .NET Fiddle, https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTFyo3